# Using curl with filename containing a dynamic date

Tags: crontab, date, curl

I'm trying to upload dynamically created log file from my local box to my FTP server. This all happens in a cron job (crontab) I run every night. It creates the file using:

`30 00 * * * touch ~/Desktop/logs/"log$(date +'\%m\%d\%y')"`

Which works just fine. However, when I try to upload the file using the same syntax:

`50 00 * * * curl -T ~/Desktop/logs/"log$(date +'\%m\%d\&y')" -u user:pass ftp://example.com/logs/`

It gives me the following error:

`date: extra Operand`

I also tried it without escaping the the %:

`curl -T ~/Desktop/logs/"log$(date +'%m%d%y')" -u user:pass ftp://example.com/logs/`

Which works in the normal command line, but when executed via the crontab, gives the following error:

`/bin/sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Any ideas how to successfully upload the daily log to my server?

Comment: Dude don't use `%m%d%Y`, use `%Y-%m-%d`!  Or equivalently `date -I`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would normally specify the date in a cron job is not to have quotes around the whole name and to use backticks around the date command, so:

```
50 00 * * * curl -T ~/Desktop/logs/log`date +'\%m\%d\%y'` -u user:pass ftp://example.com/logs/
```

Although I would expect the `$(date ...)` syntax to work aswell.

(Oh and I'm assuming the ampersand before the y in the second cron job is a typo in the question - but if it's also in your cron job that will be a problem.)

Comment: Thank you. That has worked. I don't know why the syntax I used to create the file (`touch ~/Desktop/logs/"log$(date +'\%m\%d\%y')"`) wouldn't work with rsync!

Comment: rsync, or curl?  rsync expects remote filenames to possibly contain globs and quoting, and if you were actually using rsync that might explain why it didn't work.